Can Visual Studio Code indent or unindent without reformatting?
I have some C code:
void foo() {
    if (condition) {
        some_function_call(arg1,
                           arg2);

        /*
         * Hello world.
         */
        some_function_call(arg1,
                           arg2);
    }
}

I have VS Code configured to use spaces for tabs and to use 4-space tabs.  Suppose I want to remove the if condition and unindent the block of code.  If I select the if body and press Shift+Tab, I get:
void foo() {
    if (condition) {
    some_function_call(arg1,
                        arg2);

    /*
        * Hello world.
        */
    some_function_call(arg1,
                        arg2);
    }
}

The comments and arguments are no longer aligned.  A siimlar thing happens if I were to indent instead:
void foo() {
    if (condition) {
            some_function_call(arg1,
                            arg2);

            /*
            * Hello world.
            */
            some_function_call(arg1,
                            arg2);
    }
}

Is there a way to make VS Code do a completely naive indent/unindent that inserts or removes the same number of spaces on each line?  Using a multiline cursor to insert spaces (or a tab) suffices for indenting, but it doesn't work well for unindenting: pressing backspace/delete will end up removing empty lines, and Shift+Tab with a multiline cursor produces the same output as before.
I have tried various settings for Editor: Auto Indent; they do not seem to help.

What are your Editor: Format settings? Do you have any C formatter enabled?

@Destroy666 Editor: Format on Paste, Format on Save, and Format on Type are all disabled. Editor: Default Formatter is None.  I have no language extensions installed, and do not have any C > Format: Enable option.
